# convergence of sequence in WOT, SOT & norm topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $S:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^{2}$ be the forward shift operator i.e. $S(x_1,x_2,...)=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$ then I have to show that $S^n$ converges to $0$ in WOT but not in SOT and norm toplogy.

WOT convergence can be seen as $\langle S^nx,y\rangle\rightarrow\langle0,y\rangle =0$  for all $ x,y \in \ell^2$ . Is it correct? 
 I am also not able to prove that it doesn't converge in the other two topologies.

Kindly Help!!! Thanks & Regards in advance.

Comment: Why -1 can you give reason please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't converge strongly then it doesn't converge in norm (consider the contrapositive), so try to find a counterexample there.  To show that $\{S^n\}$ does not converge strongly to $0$ consider the vector $e_1\in\ell^2$ defined by $e_1(n)=1$ if $n=1$ and $e_1(n)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: $||S^n e_1||$ is  $ ||e_{n+1}||$ but as n goes on it will also tend to zero isn't it?  Can you explain a bit more? @Aweygan

Comment: $\|S^ne_1\|=\|e_{n+1}\|=1$ for all $n$.  How could it converge to zero?

Comment: Oh yes... My bad thanx I was thinking something else